# Netbeans 7.4 PHP indent rules

Tags: php, netbeans, indentation

i have a problem with the correct auto indent (ALT + SHIFT + F) for PHP code in netbeans 7.4:

```
$this->templates = array(           
         self::TEMPLATE_COMMENT => new Template(
                    self::TEMPLATE_COMMENT, "foo" . Template::TEMPLATE_PLACEHOLDER_OBJECT_NAME . "bar", array(
                "bing" => array(':' . Template::TEMPLATE_PLACEHOLDER_OBJECT_ID . ':', 'lalala'),
                    ), Template::TEMPLATE_PLACEHOLDER_USER_IMAGE
        )
);
```

as you can see, the line starts with "bing", have the wrong indent. is this a bug or how can i prevent this?

the prefered result should like this:

```
$this->templates = array(           
         self::TEMPLATE_COMMENT => new Template(
                    self::TEMPLATE_COMMENT, "foo" . Template::TEMPLATE_PLACEHOLDER_OBJECT_NAME . "bar", array(
                            "bing" => array(':' . Template::TEMPLATE_PLACEHOLDER_OBJECT_ID . ':', 'lalala'),
                    ), Template::TEMPLATE_PLACEHOLDER_USER_IMAGE
        )
);
```

Comment: If you look at preferences, the default value for `Continuacion Indentation` is 8. You might want to make it match other indentations.

Comment: this change only the indent for line 3 and 5 :(

Comment: I assumed those were the wrong ones. What output would you like?

Comment: The question is very clear now, I hope someone else can help you (I'm actually clueless). Whatever, I've used several IDEs and they never get complex formatting right (where "right" means "to my liking") ;-)

Comment: thx! for now i use "phpstorm" without any problems...